# How to change intersect section color using svg tag

Tags: javascript, svg

Can you help to change intersect section colour in below image using svg tag.

```html
<svg width="120" height="80">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.6" />
                <circle cx="80" cy="50" r="25" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.6" />
            </svg>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new shape by clipping a copy of the right circle with the left or vice versa

```html
<svg width="120" height="80">
  <clipPath id="cp">
    <use xlink:href="#l"/>
  </clipPath>
  <g fill-opacity=".6" fill="black">
  <circle id="l" cx="50" cy="50" r="25"  />
  <circle id="r" cx="80" cy="50" r="25" />
  </g>
  
  <use xlink:href="#r" clip-path="url(#cp)" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, if I try to apply same black colour, not sure why intersect portion coming in dark black colour, is it possible to make same colour?.

Comment: The 2 circles are in a group with  fill-opacity=".6"  (in your code you are using this  fill-opacity) Apply the same  fill-opacity to the intersection

Comment: Is the ``xlink:`` notation still required in any modern browser? Its marked **deprecated** in the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href